# Why can I tab through elements behind a modal dialog in PrimeFaces 3.0.RC1?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, modal-dialog

I am having a weird issue with PrimeFaces 3.0.RC1 related to modal dialogs and elements behind the overlay: when the dialog is displayed, mouse selection of the fields behind the overlay is unavailable but I am able to tab, and even enter text, into the inputText fields underneath the dialog. The funny thing is it works as expected under 3.0.M3. Here is some test code that replicates the behaviour:

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:outputText value="Current user:"/>
        <p:commandLink onclick="confirmation.show()" value="Log Out" type="button"/>
        <p:inputText />
        <p:inputText />
        <p:inputText />
        <p:inputText />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
<p:confirmDialog appendToBody="true" id="logoutConfirmation" closable="false" message="Are you sure you want to log out?" header="Log Out" widgetVar="confirmation">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="confirmation.hide();" type="button"/>
        <p:commandButton style="float:right;" value="Log Out" actionListener="#{login.logout()}" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"/>
    </h:form>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Am I missing something?  Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: I feel that this is just another PF bug. I think it's better to just post it at their own forum/issuetracker.

Comment: That is what I was thinking.  I did post a question there, as well, but thought I would ask here in case I am simply misusing the component.  Thanks for voicing what I was thinking!

Comment: Found another thread where the user mentioned the change in PF 3.0.M4 from sam to aristo themes and the need to remove any references from aristo in web.xml.  Seems to be working now that I removed the primefaces.THEME reference.  I will do some more testing, though...

Comment: Squash that, just tested in Chrome and FireFox and it is still broken.  Opened a ticket with PF.

Answer (score -1):

Dialog tag, should be child of body tag
If it is not so, we can set appendTo attribute to "@(body)" in dialog component